# Generating random number without repetitions. Is my logic correct?

Tags: c, arrays, random, srand

I wrote the following code i order to randomly choose a word from a given array of words without choosing the same word twice. (I want to choose only 4 words). After dry running the program and testing it, everything seems to be working fun and no duplicates where encountered, however I would like to have a second verification since I am new to programming.

```
char words[10][10] = {"dog", "cat", "horse", "cow", "goat", "monkey", "elephant", "crow", "fish", "snake"};

void getRandomWords()
{
    int i = 0, k = 0;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    n = rand() % 10;
    checkRandom[k] = n;
    k ++;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j ++) {
        printf("%c\n", words[n][j]);
    }

    do {
        n = rand() % 10;

        for (int t = 0; t < 4; t ++) {
            if (checkRandom[t] == n) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
                found = 0;
        }

        if (found == 0) {
            checkRandom[k] = n;
            k ++;
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j ++) {
                printf("%c\n", words[n][j]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    } while (i < 3);
}
```

Comment: The shuffling algorithm below brings up a good point: you aren't generating pseudo-random numbers: you generating a shuffled sequence. True random sequences allow repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variant of the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle algorithm to quickly produce a randomly-ordered sequence without duplicates. A slightly simplified version of the "inside-out" algorithm is:

```
void shuffle(int *array, int length) {
    int i, value;

    array[0] = 0;

    for (i = 1 ; i < length ; i++) {
        value = rand() % (i + 1);

        array[i] = array[value];
        array[value] = i;
    }
}
```

You could do something similar to generate a random array of integers, then use those integers to index your word array.

Comment: Why do you put array[0]=0? You are not choosing randomly the first element doing so.

Comment: You can also cut F-Y short. If you only need, say, 4 items out of 10, you only need to do the first 4 iterations.

Comment: @Bob -- `value = rand() % i` can evaluate to zero, so yes, it does randomly choose the first element.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker -- Good point; one could easily short-circuit this.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that I "over simplified" this a bit.

Comment: In fact, I did over simplify this. I fixed the code above (changed `rand() % i` to `rand() % (i + 1)`) to correctly follow the inside-out algorithm.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks. Do you think that set directly array[value]=i when happens that value==i could be an improvement or it doesn't worth the extra if?

Comment: Forget it, it's worthless, I realize